# Any way a custom TabBar have transparent background?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create a bottom tabBar with react-navigation which is transparent.

I am using the "tabBarComponent: "  BottomTabNavigatorConfig. and background of the MyCustomTabBar is transparent.

Yet I am getting a white background in tabbar.

```
const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Posts: PostsStack,
    Subreddits: SubredditsScreen,
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
    Inbox: InboxScreen,
    Search: SearchScreen
  },
  {
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    lazyLoad: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      tinColor: 'transparent',
      activeTintColor: 'red',
      inactiveTintColor: 'green',
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: true,
      lazyLoad: true,
      upperCaseLabel: false,
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.6)',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderTopColor: '#996600',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    tabBarComponent: props => <TabBar {...props} />,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
      return routeName === 'Posts'
        ? { header: null }
        : { headerTitle: routeName }; // Disabled TabNavigators header for Posts screen cos It has its own header from another stacknavigator.
    }
  }
);
```

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYpE.jpg)

Comment: I notice you are mixing a custom tab bar with tabBarOptions, which will not work. You should either define the options for the default react-navigation tab bar or create a custom tab bar.

Comment: Agreed, but creating a custom tab bar with transparent background hasn't worked either.

Comment: This will probably not work using react-navigation, since the screens you are rendering inside the tab bar will be restricted to the area above the tab bar.

Comment: Got it, thanks @dentemm , your comment made me reevaluate what I was doing wrong. Did it with react-navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabBarOptions` are ignored if a `tabBarComponent` is provided.

Solution to the issue was to apply following style to the parent view of the custom  component.

```
style: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.6)',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderTopColor: '#996600',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

set in tab bar option

```
 tabBarOptions: {
        style: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      elevation: 0, 
    },
    },
```